# Freeze last date row synchronized with each image block

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make HTML for attached image. Please guide me should I use table structure or div structure for the same. I want to synchronize that last date row with particular block of color image too.

How should I achieve the same. Guide me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not tabular data, so I'd avoid using a `<table>` element for this. For your outer containers - the day containers - I'd use `<figure>`s for each day with `<figcaption>` elements for the date caption, though you could also use a `<div>` or `<section>` with a headline if you didn't trust your browser support for figure.

Within those, you seem to have numbered lists, which each list item containing an image and a bunch of colour swatches. So I'd use an ordered list `<ol>` for the outer list and each element within contains an image and then an unordered list of swatches. You can use CSS to make the unordered list items display inline, and if you used `<ol start="30">` then your ordered list would start counting from 30.